# How can I get value in the “post” router using expressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am fresh in nodejs,so as express.

Assuming I'm get the return value from in POST method, how can i get it from GET? I think,**app.use()** , I know the middleware can only handler the requests,but at the time, i have not idea.

```
 ...
 var Some = require('./Some');
 app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render({
       title:"hi",
       output: data || ''    <--------I wanna get data from below
    })
 });

 app.post('/',function(req,res){         
     var some = new Some();
     some.postOriginCode(code,function(data){
         data               <-------- here is the data i want.

         //I can do it the way,but I don't like.
         res.render('index', {output:data});
     });
 });
 ...
```

Comment: anybody give me the 3rd solution or more. ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Some = require('./Some');
app.get('/',function(req,res){
   res.render({
   title:"hi",
   output:app.get('data')
})
});

app.post('/',function(req,res){         
 var some = new Some();
 some.postOriginCode(code,function(data){
      app.set('data',data);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to process `GET` & `POST` in the same route, for for [app.all](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.all)

just like

```
app.all('/',function(req,res){ 

       //processing code here 

});
```